# How do I get a an applications width and height from another application on Windows with windows APi

Tags: c++, windows, api, height, width

Say I have calculator open. I want to query its width/height and other info.

That is the correct system call/function ?

I asked the google machine but no dice.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I know you've tagged this as C++, but I'm going to assume you do mean the C/C++ WIN API calls and not the PInvoke/.NET way?

Comment: Yes I mean Win API not Pinvoke.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Use FindWindow and then GetWindowRect. Use the Spy++ tool to get the window class parameter that you will need in FindWindow.